Hide button "Watch full video" for segmented video
I'm using Vimeo for a background video with the following embed code:
<iframe allow="autoplay" frameborder=" 0" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/73678682?autoplay=1&background=1#t=1m10s&end=1m40s"></iframe>

Since is a segmented video, Vimeo adds a button to watch the full video.

Is there a way to hide it ? Css won't work since it's inside the iframe. All the controls are already hidden in the video player settings.
